# Does anybody know a CMS with API functionality?

Tags: api, content-management-system

I am looking for a CMS that offers an API for managing the several content elements or pages.

The programming language(or other technical details) of the CMS doesn't matter - so don't hesitate give an answer:).

Best regards

Comment: All CMS's have API's.  What are you asking?  Do you want specific features in the API?  Do you want a specific language to support the API well?  What are you asking?

Comment: I am looking for an API, that I can access from other web applications to administrate my content elements managed in this CMS.

Comment: https://prismic.io, http://www.contentful.com, http://www.osmek.com

Comment: http://defaqto.io can be used to store pages, html blocks, custom variables, blogs, etc. all pulled into your app via a REST API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umbraco has a REST API called Base (http://umbraco.org/documentation/books/introduction-to-base)

It also has a pretty good .net code API too.

Comment: this is a good example - thanks!

Comment: Updated link for Umbraco "/Base" : http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-base

Answer (score 4):

[StorageRoom](http://storageroomapp.com) is a JSON-based CMS that might help you. We built it exactly for this.

Edit: StorageRoom has become [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com), a cloud-based CMS with a powerful API.

Answer (score 1):

[Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) offers an API that allows content manipulation. More info [here](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS).
This API implements the [CMIS](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/cmis/charter.php) standard, which you might prefer to a proprietary API.

Answer (score 0):

At one level, you could use any standard web host and the API is called "FTP" (or WebDAV). :-)

As CMSes work through the web, you can usually construct POST requests emulating their built in edit forms very easily. Also, most CMSes store their data in an SQL database, and it is often very easy to add content to the database yourself, making it appear on the site. I think that the other functions of the CMS are a far more important factor.

There is an emerging standard for CMS APIs, called [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services). I don't know if it is getting any traction.

Comment: watch my comment at the top - this is not what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Check out osmek.  Its a centrally hosted system where you interact with your content through an API

Answer (score -1):

INZU is a cloud cms with a JSON and XML API plus it includes e-commerce and cart management system [www.inzu.net](http://www.inzu.net)